# Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'. Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'

Tags: react-native

when I want to run my react-native project I get this error. It was in github and before I cloned it it was working.

```
Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.react:react-native:+.
     Required by:
         project :app
         project :app > project :react-native-vector-icons
         project :app > project :react-native-async-storage_async-storage
         project :app > project :react-native-community_checkbox
         project :app > project :react-native-community_geolocation
         project :app > project :react-native-community_masked-view
         project :app > project :react-native-community_slider
         project :app > project :react-native-geocoder
         project :app > project :react-native-gesture-handler
         project :app > project :react-native-maps
         project :app > project :react-native-reanimated
         project :app > project :react-native-safe-area-context
         project :app > project :react-native-screens
         project :app > project :react-native-svg
      > Failed to list versions for com.facebook.react:react-native.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
```

Answer (score 0):

First, type the following address in your browser,
https://firebase.google.com
and if you get a 403 error, it means that the IPs of your place of residence are blocked . There are several things you can do to solve this problem:

- Uninstall Chrome browser from your system because they use it for location
- Use a valid VPN Or VPS, preferably from Germany, France or the United States
- Change your system clock to the clock of the country to which your IP has changed

Comment: I solved the problem by removing jCenter from android/build.gradle file.When I searched for solution I saw that jCenter() was shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

Bin tray is experiencing some issues on their download network :

https://status.bintray.com/

Also if you are using obselete **jCenter**(), then replace it with **mavenCentral**() in your **android/build.gradle**

Comment: Yes sir I made what you wrore above and that problem is solved,but now I am in a trouble for diffrent problem

Comment: What is the new problem?

Comment: the new problem is that when I want to release an apk I faced with Type com.reactnativecommunity.asyncstorage.AsyncLocalStorageUtil is defined multiple times problems. My react-native version is 0.66.4,react-native-reanimated version is 2.3.1 , react-native-jitsi-meet version is 2.1.2 and ı exclude react-native-async-storage in android/app/build.gradle implementation of react-native-jitsi-meet

Comment: please help me for that problem.I have been trying to solve for 4 days and I could not solve :(

Comment: in your package.json, search the keyword **async**, are there 2 packages installed? There are 2 asyncstorage in react native, **@react-native-async-storage/async-storage** and **@react-native-community/async-storage**

Comment: No sir I know @react-native-community/async-storage is deprecated and I removed it before and I cleaned cache but still I face with this issue, If u have time I can share with u the code which is on github

Comment: please share it

Comment: Can u write your github name

Comment: ShenoyAkshay123